# Removing a key value pair from mongoose schema using findOneAndUpdate() method

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

In the following is the section of code :

Profile is a mongoose shcema object and contains multiple key-value pairs and the function of the code is to update Profile using findOneAndUpdate method passing in profileFields to `$set` which contains the new key-value pairs.

```
let profile = await Profile.findOne({ user: req.user.id });
            if (profile) {
                profile = await Profile.findOneAndUpdate(
                    { user: req.user.id },
                    { $set: profileFields },
                    { new: true }
                );
                console.log(profile);
                return res.json(profile);
            }
```

This code works fine when a value for a key is changed.

eg. Profile.githubusername was abcd and is changed by passing profileFields(in which githubusername is xyz) to `$set` in the findOneAndUpdate method.

But the code fails when a key-value pair is completely removed.

eg. profileFields object does not contain githubusername key.
In such case the earlier previously stored value of Profile.githubusername persists.

But I need all existing information for profile to be replaced by profileFields such that if a key-value pair is missing from profileFields it is also removed from profile.

Is there a way to achieve this?

TIA

Edit :
I added the following before making the call to findOneAndUpdate(). But this still doesn't work.

```
let profile = await Profile.findOne({ user: req.user.id });
            // for (key in profile)
            //     console.log(key);
            for (key in profile) {
                if (Object.keys(profileFields).indexOf(key) === -1) {
                    console.log('missing key: 'key);
                    profileFields[key] = '';
                }
            }
```

When I console.log(profile) I get:

```
{
   skills: [ 'HTML' ],
   _id: 60142f8f9a5bff1f08653478,
   user: 60142dc89a5bff1f08653477,
   company: 'Self Employed',
   bio: 'Useless international',
   status: 'Student or Learning',
   experience: [],
   education: [],
   date: 2021-01-29T15:53:51.693Z,
   __v: 10,
   location: 'Ahemdabad, Gujrat, India',       
   githubusername: 'k'
 }
```

From what I understand skills, _id, user, company, bio ... githubusername are the only keys in this object.

But on running a `for (key in profile)` loop I get a lot a other keys as well ,some are :

```
$__
isNew
errors
$locals
$op
_doc
$init
db
discriminators
schema
collection
$__originalValidate
$__save
$__validate
$__remove
$__deleteOne
$__init
$isMongooseModelPrototype
$__handleSave
save
$__delta
$__version
increment
$__where
remove
delete
```

How can I loop through only the user defined keys?

Comment: Is there a reason you cannot check if the value of the key-value pair is null/empty and then use findOneAndDelete?

Comment: @anthony There are going to be a lot of call made to this function but only a tiny few will need complete deletion of a pair, hence I wanted to avoid the extra work for every call

Comment: @anthony please check the edited question

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
 delete mongooseObject["$init"]
```

it will delete your key and then u can manipulate other keys